# Variation of Argument definition

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have some questions regarding what in my textbook is defined as the "variation of the argument" of a holomorphic function $f$ over a non self-intersecting contour $C \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

First, the author claims that given a contour $C$ parameterized by a surjective curve $\phi : [0, 1] \rightarrow C$ and a function $f$ which is holomorphic on a neighborhood of C not vanishing on C, there is an open, simply connected domain $\Omega$ such that $\Omega \cap C = C \setminus\{\phi(0), \phi(1)\}$ with $f(s) \neq 0$, $\forall s \in \Omega$. Is such a domain simply the neighborhood of $C$ on which the function $f$ is defined? How can such a domain be derived?

Second, the author defines the "variation of the argument of $f$ along $C$" as

$$\Delta_{C}arg f(s) = \mathcal{Im} \Big [ log \big [f(\phi(1^{-}))\big ] - log \big [f(\phi(0^{+}))\big ] \Big ]$$

And claims this is equivalent to the logarithmic derivative of $f$,

$$\mathcal{Im} \Big [ \oint\limits_{C} \frac{f^{'}(s)}{f(s)} ds \Big ]$$

I'm not sure how these two forms are equal, I can kind of see intuitively from just the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I'm not sure how this would be made rigorous. This is actually a number theory book, and I don't have as strong a background in complex analysis, so I'm not entirely sure how to reason about this.

Comment: Any neighborhood of $C$ will include its endpoints, so it's not quite that; you're close though. It's a neighborhood of $C\setminus\{\phi(0), \phi(1)\}$, which we can get by taking the derivative at each point along this and determining $f$ does not vanish so there is a small ball in which $f'$ is nonzero. Taking the union of all these balls gives the desired neighborhood. Note the endpoints are cut out since the two-sided derivative does not exist there, though one could modify the argument using one-sided derivatives which would then including the endpoints and yield some neighborhood of $C$

Comment: The answer to your second question is a theorem known as the [Argument Principle, whose Wikipedia page can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). Any reasonable introductory book to complex analysis will contain a proof.